# Getting PayPal subscription user options on0/os0 and on1/os1 using API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

Using PayPal api or web hooks, how can I get the value of subscription optional field filled by user ? I use `on0`/`os0` and `on1`/`os1` like below.
But if I get subscription details I only get subscription ID, status, subscription title at most, but cannot find a way to getch the 2 custom fields filled by user.

If it matters, the subscription button is made by the html code on web site, not a predefined subscription in PayPal account.

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="user_url">
<input name="os0" type="url" size="70"  placeholder="enter your URL" required>

<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="user_url_title">
<input name="os1" type="text" size="70" placeholder="enter your url title" required>
```

I see [PayPal mentions these on1/os1 valiables here](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html-example-cart/#link-productoptions) but I cannot find much info about them in the API calls.

Comment: That data comes in via PayPal IPN. You've used that tag: are you using IPN?

Comment: Not using the IPN for this, I was using the API to get data of existent subscriptions that were already created without specifying an IPN url. If you say that data exists in IPN notifications, then I will try it now by specifying a global ipn url on my PayPal account.